# Make a button take 25% of a linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Ok, so I need a button to always take up 25% of a linear layout no matter whats in it. The other 75% will be a TextView field.
Here is what I have so far:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp "
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
</LinearLayout>
```

However, at 0dp the button goes away, and at wrap_content it will always choose the text to set the width. How do I force it to use the weight as its method to set width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this....

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This worked. Although I did add a weightSum = "4" under orientation.

Comment: Could you please explain to me why I don't? I am not trying to be rude, I just don't understand. How does the code know that 3 is equal to 75% and  1 is 25%? Does it take all the layout_weights and total them for you?

Comment: umm...you can say that android does it for you..however there are no stiff logic because android keeps on challenging your logic always in case of layouts and adapters....you will experience it later...:)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content "
    android:layout_weight=".75"
    android:text="" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the 0dp to height, make it wrapcontent instead

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content "
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:text="" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".75"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using orietation as horizontal then use

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:weightSum="1">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:text="" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".75"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
```

If you are using orientation as vertical then use

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp "
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:text="" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".75"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
```